# Weird Readings with DAGU IR COMPOUND EYE (IR SENSORS)

Tags: c++, arduino, infrared

I am new to this forum and arduino. I have been testing with the IR COMPOUND EYE from dagu..
Trying to use it as a range detector..

I am aware that the maximum range is 200mm.
But when i compile and run the following code on my arduino UNO.. I get strange readings:

```
void IReye() {

     digitalWrite(IRleds,HIGH);                           // turn on IR     LEDs to read TOTAL IR LIGHT (ambient + reflected)
    delayMicroseconds(500);                           // Allow time   for phototransistors to respond. (may not be needed)
    leftIRvalue=analogRead(IRleft);                  // TOTAL IR    = AMBIENT IR + LED IR REFLECTED FROM OBJECT
    rightIRvalue=analogRead(IRright);            // TOTAL IR = AMBIENT IR + LED IR REFLECTED FROM OBJECT
    upIRvalue=analogRead(IRup);                   // TOTAL IR = AMBIENT IR + LED IR REFLECTED FROM OBJECT
    downIRvalue=analogRead(IRdown);         // TOTAL IR = AMBIENT IR + LED IR REFLECTED FROM OBJECT

    digitalWrite(IRleds,LOW);                  // turn off IR LEDs to read AMBIENT IR LIGHT (IR from indoor lighting and sunlight)
    delayMicroseconds(500);                // Allow time for phototransistors to respond. (may not be needed)
    leftIRvalue=leftIRvalue-analogRead(IRleft);            // REFLECTED IR = TOTAL IR - AMBIENT IR
    rightIRvalue=rightIRvalue-analogRead(IRright);   // REFLECTED IR = TOTAL IR - AMBIENT IR
    upIRvalue=upIRvalue-analogRead(IRup);      // REFLECTED IR = TOTAL IR - AMBIENT IR
    downIRvalue=downIRvalue-analogRead(IRdown);       // REFLECTED IR = TOTAL IR - AMBIENT IR

    distance=(leftIRvalue+rightIRvalue+upIRvalue+downIRvalue)/4; // distance of object is average of reflected IR
     Serial.println(distance);
     Serial.print("\n");


}
```

The readings i get when the obstacle is close is: 800 - 900
when no obstacle and the EYE is made to face the ceiling - i get it 40-80..

Are these the values that are supposed to appear or is something wrong with the code or my IR SENSOR..

// VALues without any obstacle (faces ceiling)
82.00

82.00

82.00

83.00

82.00

82.00

84.00

86.00

88.00

91.00

94.00

99.00

// Values when hand placed 4 cm
969.00

969.00

969.00

969.00

970.00

970.00

970.00

970.00

Any help is appreciated.. 
Thanks in Advance